# От(того) слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Есть два предложения, которые следуют один за другим. 
"Я был в шоке от того, что произошло. Я был в шоке от(того), что это произошло". Как во втором предложении пишется "от(того"), слитно или раздельно? И возможно ли двоякое написание?

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, во втором случае возможно только слитное написание ***оттого.***

В нём ***оттого = потому.***

Answer (score 1):

"Я был в шоке от того, что произошло.  Местоименно-определительное придаточное. ЧТО - союзное слово. Местоименная пара: ТОГО (указ. слово) - ЧТО (союзное слово).

Я был в шоке оттого, что это произошло". Я был в шоке, оттого что это произошло". Придаточное со значением причины. ОТТОГО ЧТО - союз, расчленение факультативно.

Разная структура, разный смысл, разная орфография. Местоименная связь и союзная связь придаточных в СПП.

Answer (score 0):

Во втором предложении "оттого" - это наречие причины и пишется слитно

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, это стилистический приём синтаксического параллелизма. Если предложения стоят рядом, то и смысл у них один: не почему был в шоке-оттого=потому, а именно от чего, от какого события.Только в первом случае шок вообще от события, а во втором усиливается - именно от этого события.

Если бы они стояли отдельно, фразового ударения на ЭТО могло и не быть, тогда можно было бы писать слитно.